# How are temporary objects created and what's the actual operations that takes place?

Tags: c++, destructor, copy-constructor, temporary-objects

Can anyone Explain how the output of this code is :

```
deleting 0xbfc69f7c  3,7
deleting 0xbfc69f84  2,4
deleting 0xbfc69f8c  1,3
```

Why aren't temporary objects destructor getting called which was created during the return from overloaded + operator. Is the Fraction object created inside the + function and its temporary copy are same and destructor is called just once, I guess that should not be the case. Can anyone explain what the actual operations that are taking place here.

Thanks in advance!

```
class Fraction{

    int num ; 
    int den ;
    public:
    Fraction( int x = 0  , int y = 0  ){ num = x ; den =  y ;  }
    Fraction( const Fraction & f ){

        cout<<"Copy Constructor for "<<f.num<<" , "<<f.den<<endl ;
        num = f.num ;
        den = f.den ; 

    }
    Fraction operator+( const Fraction& f) const{

        int x = f.num + num ; 
        int y = f.den + den  ;

        return Fraction(x,y) ; 

    }

    ~Fraction(){

        cout<<"deleting "<<this<<"  "<<num<<","<<den<<endl ; 

    }

};

int main() {

    Fraction f1(1,3);
    Fraction f2( 2, 4 );
    Fraction f3 = f1 + f2 ; 

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

It's because of [return value optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization) and [copy elision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_elision) (thanks to  Joachim). The temporary object will be eliminated.

Answer (score 1):

This line doesn't create a new `Fraction` and then copy it to `f3`:

`Fraction f3 = f1 + f2 ;`

It initializes `f3` with the contents of `f1` and then the `+` operator is used to add `f2`. No temporary object is created and deleted. E.g. The *copy constructor* of `Fraction` is used instead of the *assignment operator*. A temporary object would be created and the *assignment operator* used in this case :

```
Fraction f3;
f3 = f1 + f2;
```

As others have pointed out, the compiler will optimize the use of the *copy constructor* and avoid (elide) the copy of `f1` to `f3` even if you build in debug mode.

Comment: No, the copy-constructor is used to initialize the `f3` object, however it's [*elided*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_elision).

Comment: @JoachimPileborg you are right of course, I typed carelessly. fixed now

Comment: Please can you explain, what do you mean by its elided ?

Comment: Instead of creating an object to hold the result of `f1 + f2` and then copying it to `f3` it stores the result of `f1 + f2` directly to `f3`. This is an important optimization that is even applied in debug builds.

Comment: Thanks for helping @ManosNikolaidis !